# Django impossible bug with exists()

Tags: python, django

Is there a possible explanation to this?
The queryset is supposed to be empty, but len() returns 1 object. But when I try to access the object, it does not exist. Never seen that before.

```
(Pdb) self.service_ride_windows_set.all()
*** RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: RideWindow has no ride.
(Pdb) self.service_ride_windows_set.all().exists()
True
(Pdb) len(self.service_ride_windows_set.all())
1
(Pdb) self.service_ride_windows_set.all()[0]
*** RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: RideWindow has no ride.
(Pdb) self.service_ride_windows_set.get()
*** RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: RideWindow has no ride.
(Pdb)
```

Comment: You should show your models. Looks like the error is actually happening in the unicode/str method for ServiceRideWindow, which is trying to call a further relation.

Comment: Building on top of @DanielRoseman, it should work if you do `ride = self.service_ride_windows_set.all()[0]`, and then you can do things like `type(ride)`, but is expected to fail if you do `print ride`, given the behaviour.

Comment: Thank both of you, it was indeed in the `__unicode__` method. I just didn't pay attention to the message itself :)